# Ngrok "HTTP Error 404". The requested resource is not found

Tags: python, django, ngrok

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdm8Z.png)

I've tried to execute my django-app with "ngrok". Added url to "ALLOWED_HOSTS" and other variables which need that. I did 'py manage.py runserver' and 'ngrok http 80' together => no result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few hours later, I figure out that you must run your ngrok from CMD, not from IDE Terminal.

P.S. If you set domain in 'C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\ **hosts**' for your local address, that command help may help you:

> ngrok http --host-header=rewrite **mysite.com:80**

where ***mysite.com*** - your domain name, **:80** - your port.

Comment: For me it worked on the IDE command line of VSCODE, but when using port 80 I got the error "Too many redirects". When I changed from port 80 to port 443 it worked like a charm:
.../ngrok http --host-header=rewrite mydomain.test:443

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to have Stripe webhooks connect to my localhost via ngrok, but the incoming requests were seeing `404`s (weird, because these had worked in the past and nothing in the app nor stripe api had changed).

Ngrok didn't give any error message either, and it wasn't displaying the requests in the terminal as it usually would (I could see the 404 from the Stripe dashboard).

Solution: I upgraded ngrok to the most recent version (`brew upgrade ngrok`), started a new terminal and started ngrok in the usual way, and the problem was gone.